How to loop through without using clear
I am trying to write a dice game: I am just trying to make some sort of animation for dice roll GIF like
but currently in this code it all prints all at once whole 6 dice. I just want one die that loops through all dice numbers like a GIF, I tried using clear but it clears whole screen and clears print statements also.
// DICE GAME
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "rand.h"

struct user {
    int bet;
    int guess;
    int balance;
} user;

struct ASCII {
    char ASCII[60];
} ascii[6];

void dice_animation() {
    strcpy(ascii[0].ASCII, "---------\n|\t|\n|   O\t|\n|\t|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[1].ASCII, "---------\n|O\t|\n|\t|\n|      O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[2].ASCII, "---------\n|O\t|\n|   O   |\n|      O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[3].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|\t|\n|O     O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[4].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|   O   |\n|O     O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[5].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|O     O|\n|O     O|\n---------\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%s", ascii[i].ASCII);
        sleep(1);
        // system("clear");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
    printf("%s", ascii[user.guess-1].ASCII);
}

int _random(int max, int min);

int DICE, bet_return, random_return;

void error() {
    if (user.guess < 1 || user.guess > 6) {
        printf("Your guess should be within 1 to 6\n");
        printf("Your guess i.e : %d is INVALID\n", user.guess);
    }
    else if (user.bet > user.balance) {
        printf("Your bet :%d exceeds your balance:%d\n", user.bet, user.balance);
    }
    else if (bet_return == 0 || random_return == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void game_logic() {
    printf("GENERATING A RANDOM NUMBER ......\n");
    DICE = _random(6, 0);
    dice_animation(user.guess);
    //rand() % (max_number + 1 - minimum_number) + minimum_number
    printf("Random Number : %d Your guess : %d\n",DICE,user.guess);
    if (user.guess == DICE) {
        user.balance += (user.bet * 3);
        printf("CORRECT GUESS :+%d\n", user.bet * 3);
    } else {
        user.balance -= (user.bet * 3);
        printf("WRONG GUESS :-%d\n",user.bet * 3);
        if (user.balance < 0) {
            printf("CURRENTLY IN DEBT\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    //starting balance
    user.balance = 1000;
    do {
        printf("-------------------------------------\n");
        printf("BALANCE : %d\n", user.balance);
        printf("Please place a bet:\n");
        bet_return = scanf("%d",&user.bet);
        if (user.bet <= user.balance && bet_return == 1) {
            printf("Please guess a number from 1 to 6:\n");
            random_return = scanf("%d",&user.guess);
            switch (user.guess) {
              case 1:
              case 2:
              case 3:
              case 4:
              case 5:
              case 6:
                game_logic();
                break;
              default:
                error();
                continue;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            error();
            continue;
        }
    } while (user.balance > 0 && bet_return != 0 && random_return != 0);
}

I tried using clear but it cleared whole screen including print statements
I am expecting a single dice that loops through all 1 to 6

Considering your use of the <unistd.h> header file, I assume you're on a Linux (or macOS) system. Then you can use ncurses for precise terminal control, including writing at specific positions.

On a different note, please be careful when using tabs in output. The end-user might not have the same tab settings as you, meaning the output won't be aligned properly. Use actual spaces instead.

i am on Linux system sir , i am just trying to make a ASCII type GIF animation of dice roll , also i dont know about ncurses , i will have to leaern it sir, thanks for the info

ncurses is definitely the right move here, but for simpler (single-line) animations, you can use the backspace character (0x08) to edit the current line. Usually in conjunction with usleep calls for timing.

Try using terminal escape codes.
For example printf ( "\033[2J"); clears the screen and printf ( "\033[10;1H"); moves the cursor to row 10 column 1.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#inclued <time.h>
struct user{
    int bet;
    int guess;
    int balance;
}user;
struct ASCII {
    char ASCII[60];
}ascii[6];

void dice_animation() {
    strcpy(ascii[0].ASCII, "---------\n|\t|\n|   O\t|\n|\t|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[1].ASCII, "---------\n|O\t|\n|\t|\n|      O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[2].ASCII, "---------\n|O\t|\n|   O   |\n|      O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[3].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|\t|\n|O     O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[4].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|   O   |\n|O     O|\n---------\n");
    strcpy(ascii[5].ASCII, "---------\n|O     O|\n|O     O|\n|O     O|\n---------\n");

    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
        printf ( "\033[10;1H"); // move to row 10 col 1
        printf ( "\033[0J");//clear screen below cursor
        printf("%s",ascii[i].ASCII);
        sleep(1);
        // system("clear");
    }
    printf ( "\033[10;1H"); // move to row 10 col 1
    printf ( "\033[0J");//clear screen below cursor

    printf("******************\n");
    printf("%s",ascii[user.guess-1].ASCII);
}

int DICE , bet_return ,random_return ;
void error(){
    if(user.guess < 1 || user.guess > 6){
        printf("Your guess should be within 1 to 6\n");
        printf("Your guess i.e : %d is INVALID\n",user.guess);
    }
    else if(user.bet > user.balance){
        printf("Your bet :%d exceeds your balance:%d\n",user.bet,user.balance);
    }
    else if(bet_return == 0 || random_return == 0){
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        exit(0);
    }
}

void game_logic(){
    printf("GENERATING A RANDOM NUMBER ......\n");
    DICE = 1 + rand ( ) % 6;
    dice_animation ( user.guess);
    //rand() % (max_number + 1 - minimum_number) + minimum_number
    printf("Random Number : %d Your guess : %d\n",DICE,user.guess);
    if (user.guess == DICE) {
        user.balance += (user.bet * 3);
        printf("CORRECT GUESS :+%d\n",user.bet * 3);
    }
    else{
        user.balance -= (user.bet * 3);
        printf("WRONG GUESS :-%d\n",user.bet * 3);
        if(user.balance < 0 ){
            printf("CURRENTLY IN DEBT\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    srand ( time ( NULL));
    printf ( "\033[1;1H"); // move to row 1 col 1
    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen
    //starting balance
    user.balance = 1000;
    do{
        printf ( "\033[8;1H"); // move to row 8 col 1
        printf ( "\033[1J");//clear screen above cursor
        printf ( "\033[1;1H"); // move to row 1 col 1
        printf("-------------------------------------\n");
        printf("BALANCE : %d\n",user.balance);
        printf("Please place a bet:\n");
        bet_return = scanf("%d",&user.bet);
        if ( user.bet <= user.balance && bet_return == 1){
            printf("Please guess a number from 1 to 6:\n");
            random_return = scanf("%d",&user.guess);


            printf ( "\033[0J");//clear screen below cursor
            switch(user.guess){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                game_logic();
                break;
            default:
                error();
                continue;
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            error();
            continue;
        }
    }while(user.balance > 0 && bet_return != 0 && random_return !=0);
    printf ( "\033[1;1H"); // move to row 1 col 1
    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen
}


sir
for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
        printf ( "\033[10;1H"); // move to row 10 col 1
        printf ( "\033[0J");
        printf("%s",ascii[i].ASCII);
        sleep(1);
        // system("clear");
}
printf("%s",ascii[user.guess-1].ASCII);
}

when printf("%s",ascii[user.guess-1].ASCII);
is printed  i wanna remove the previous loop result
How can i do that?


Thank you so much sir , It finally worked also where can i know more about these \033[10;1H? i didn't understand anything

BTW, clearing the screen (no matter how you do it) is always a very expensive operation — one not suited to games. Better to either design your game to update only specific cells per drawing operation, or keep track of which cells need updating (ncurses does this behind the scenes). It is also worth selecting the alternate screen buffer for use by your program; your users will like you more and your program will not have to deal with cells in invisible/scrolled-off areas — making for a snappier user experience.
